# Why @FocusState Crashing SwiftUI Preview

Tags: swiftui

Okay, I wanted to know why my preview wasn't working after updating Xcode. So I have an enum that looks like this.

```
enum Field {
    case email
    case securedPassword
    case unsecuredPassword
}
```

Now when I add @FocusState to my TestView my preview just crashes and doesn't update. Here is how my code looks like.

```
struct TestView1: View {
    @FocusState var focusedField: Field?
    
    var body: some View {
        Color.blue
    }
}
```

Now when I comment out the @FocusState I am able to change the color to something like red and the preview updates. When the @FocusState is not commented out, when I change the color to something new it doesn't update the preview and gives me a weird crash.

Now is this a bug and if so is there a work around?

Comment: Looks like Xcode defect

Comment: have you tried cleaning the project? Can you mention the Xcode version you are using? BTW it works for me, I am on Xcode 13.1

Comment: @Asperi so its a bug then? Is there way around this?

Comment: @JarvisTheAvenger Xcode 13.2.1 yeah was working b4 but I updated and preview stop working

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Please see my related answer I posted a couple of months ago on the Apple Developer Forums located at: https://developers.apple.com/forums/thread/681571?answerId=690251022#690251022 .
Does this work for you?

```swift
struct TestView1: View {
    enum Field: Hashable {
        case email
        case securedPassword
        case unsecuredPassword
    }

    @FocusState var focusedField: Field?
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Color.blue
        }
    }
}

struct TestView1_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        // Here we've wrapped `TestView1` in a `ZStack { ... }` View
        // so that it won't be the top-level View in our Preview, to avoid
        // the known bug that causes the `@FocusState` property of a
        // top-level View rendered inside of a Preview, to not work properly.
        ZStack {
            TestView1()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah that did it by nesting the TestView1 into a ZStack inside the preview. Thanks.

Comment: You're very welcome, @LuisRamirez. I'm glad I could help :)! I'm pretty sure I did report this bug to Apple, but it *might* have been as a part of my bug report I submitted to them about the on-screen keyboard not showing in SwiftUI Preview's run in the Xcode Previews app on a physical iPhone after tapping on a TextField, until the app has first been sent into the background and then brought back into the foreground...

Comment: Decent workaround for something needs to addressed by Apple.  Has anyone reported this to Apple Feedback?
https://feedbackassistant.apple.com

Comment: @Jack, I think that I did report it to Apple via their feedback assistant tool, but I'm not 100% sure I did (if I did it would have been months ago). Having said that, I've read repeatedly online people claiming that Apple encourages multiple people to report the same bugs to them, as that assists them with knowing how they ought to prioritise bug fixes based on what's most important to the development community. But I don't know if that claim is true or is just a false rumour. So feel free to report it yourself to Apple if you'd like to :).

Comment: @JeremyPearson Thanks a ton!!, submitted a feedback fingers crossed

Comment: Thanks!  I was going a little crazy trying to figure out what I was doing wrong :). I also submitted feedback.  Hopefully a lot of people are reporting this.

Comment: Adding the ZStack in the preview fixed the issue for me.  Thanks