# Xcode 13.2 SwiftUI Preview Crashes

Tags: xcode, swiftui, crash, preview

I am learning SwiftUI on [100 Days of SwiftUI on Hacking with Swift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/100/swiftui). My Xcode SwiftUI Preview crashes and I don't know why. Running on Simulator works though. I tried to completely reinstall Xcode (deleting the app, preferences, libraries etc), but it still doesn't work. I am using Xcode 13.2.1 on iMac 2019 i9 9900K 64GB RAM.

Here is the problem details. (cannot contain full report because of 30000 word limit)

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 4 Illegal instruction: 4
Terminating Process: exc handler [4180]

Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
CoreSimulator 783.5 - Device: iPod touch (7th generation) (B14B5709-F815-4854-ADB6-E7102668056B) - Runtime: iOS 15.2 (19C51) - DeviceType: iPod touch (7th generation)
dyld4 config: DYLD_ROOT_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/minsoochoo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WeSplit-ctmzuorhwkvroxgikiijvbbbfwyq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Previews/WeSplit/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot//System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PreviewsInjection.framework/PreviewsInjection DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Users/minsoochoo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WeSplit-ctmzuorhwkvroxgikiijvbbbfwyq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Previews/WeSplit/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
dyld4 config: DYLD_ROOT_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/minsoochoo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WeSplit-ctmzuorhwkvroxgikiijvbbbfwyq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Previews/WeSplit/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot//System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PreviewsInjection.framework/PreviewsInjection DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Users/minsoochoo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WeSplit-ctmzuorhwkvroxgikiijvbbbfwyq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Previews/WeSplit/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator


Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: BSXPCCnx:com.apple.dt.xcode-previews.systemservices (BSCnx:client:com.apple.dt.uv.agent-preview-nonui-service)
0   SwiftUI                             0x7fff5c970f89 static FocusState._makeProperty<A>(in:container:fieldOffset:inputs:) + 160
1   SwiftUI                             0x7fff5c97141e protocol witness for static DynamicProperty._makeProperty<A>(in:container:fieldOffset:inputs:) in conformance FocusState<A> + 25
2   SwiftUI                             0x7fff5d17717c _DynamicPropertyBuffer.addFields<A>(_:container:inputs:baseOffset:) + 131
3   SwiftUI                             0x7fff5d17709a _DynamicPropertyBuffer.init<A>(fields:container:inputs:baseOffset:) + 111
4   SwiftUI                             0x7fff5ce5d24c project #1 <A><A1>(flags:) in closure #1 in BodyAccessor.makeBody(container:inputs:fields:) + 413
5   SwiftUI                             0x7fff5ce5d0a4 closure #1 in BodyAccessor.makeBody(container:inputs:fields:) + 113
6   SwiftUI                             0x7fff5ce5ebf1 partial apply for closure #1 in BodyAccessor.makeBody(container:inputs:fields:) + 54
7   SwiftUI                             0x7fff5ce5ec12 partial apply for thunk for @callee_guaranteed (@unowned UnsafeMutablePointer<_GraphInputs>) -> (@out _GraphValue<A.BodyAccessor.Body>, @out _DynamicPropertyBuffer?, @error @owned Error) + 27
8   libswiftCore.dylib                  0x7fff3083190c withUnsafePointer<A, B>(to:_:) + 12
9   libswiftCore.dylib                  0x7fff309f2259 withUnsafeMutablePointer<A, B>(to:_:) + 9
10  SwiftUI                             0x7fff5ce5c68a BodyAccessor.makeBody(container:inputs:fields:) + 286
11  SwiftUI                             0x7fff5c94b39e static View.makeBody(view:inputs:fields:) + 160
12  SwiftUI                             0x7fff5c94b0f6 static View.makeViewList(view:inputs:) + 342
13  SwiftUI                             0x7fff5c94a5f4 static View._makeViewList(view:inputs:) + 104
14  WeSplit                                0x102730029 protocol witness for static View._makeViewList(view:inputs:) in conformance ContentView + 9
15  SwiftUI                             0x7fff5ce641cb AnyViewStorage.makeViewList(view:inputs:) + 550
16  SwiftUI                             0x7fff5ce6526a closure #2 in AnyViewList.updateValue() + 587
17  SwiftUI                             0x7fff5ce64e76 AnyViewList.updateValue() + 976
18  SwiftUI                             0x7fff5c83af29 partial apply for specialized implicit closure #2 in implicit closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in Attribute.init<A>(_:) + 15
19  AttributeGraph                      0x7fff4ff9b37b AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update() + 553
20  AttributeGraph                      0x7fff4ff9b971 AG::Graph::update_attribute(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, unsigned int) + 411
21  AttributeGraph                      0x7fff4ffa1656 AG::Graph::value_ref(AG::AttributeID, AGSwiftMetadata const*, unsigned char&) + 128
22  AttributeGraph                      0x7fff4ffb877a AGGraphGetValue + 291
23  SwiftUI                             0x7fff5c8b67bd TestableViewContent.list.getter + 47
24  SwiftUI                             0x7fff5c8b64a6 TestableViewContent.children.getter + 41
25  SwiftUI                             0x7fff5c8b61f2 View.withChildrenForTest<A>(environment:options:body:) + 181
26  SwiftUI                             0x7fff5cc7de3f View._allPreviews.getter + 88
27  SwiftUI                             0x7fff5cc7ddbe MakePreviews.visit<A>(type:) + 128
28  SwiftUI                             0x7fff5d1a5afc _callVisitViewType2 + 34
29  SwiftUI                             0x7fff5cc7dd18 static _PreviewProvider._allPreviews.getter + 165
30  PreviewsInjection                      0x102ae7f6f 0x102ac4000 + 147311
31  PreviewsInjection                      0x102ae7ea3 0x102ac4000 + 147107
32  PreviewsInjection                      0x102ae04b6 0x102ac4000 + 115894
33  PreviewsInjection                      0x102adc85d 0x102ac4000 + 100445
34  PreviewsInjection                      0x102adc265 0x102ac4000 + 98917
35  PreviewsInjection                      0x102adc519 0x102ac4000 + 99609
36  BoardServices                       0x7fff261a2c1c +[BSXPCServiceConnectionProxy invokeMethod:onTarget:withMessage:forConnection:] + 1596
37  BoardServices                       0x7fff261b0884 __63-[BSXPCServiceConnectionEventHandler connection:handleMessage:]_block_invoke + 562
38  BoardServices                       0x7fff261d9879 BSXPCServiceConnectionExecuteCallOut + 325
39  BoardServices                       0x7fff261b04cf -[BSXPCServiceConnectionEventHandler connection:handleMessage:] + 172
40  BoardServices                       0x7fff261d8bd7 -[BSXPCServiceConnection _connection_handleMessage:fromPeer:withHandoff:] + 679
41  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7fff2011265a _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
42  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7fff2011383a _dispatch_client_callout + 8
43  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7fff20119e0c _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 743
44  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7fff2011aa07 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 455
45  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7fff20120ba5 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 848
46  CoreFoundation                      0x7fff2036c84d __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
47  CoreFoundation                      0x7fff203670aa __CFRunLoopRun + 2772
48  CoreFoundation                      0x7fff203660f3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 567
49  GraphicsServices                    0x7fff2c995cd3 GSEventRunModal + 139
50  UIKitCore                           0x7fff25059f42 -[UIApplication _run] + 928
51  UIKitCore                           0x7fff2505eb5e UIApplicationMain + 101
52  SwiftUI                             0x7fff5d0d5dcf closure #1 in KitRendererCommon(_:) + 196
53  SwiftUI                             0x7fff5d0d5d09 runApp<A>(_:) + 148
54  SwiftUI                             0x7fff5cabdbad static App.main() + 61
55  WeSplit                                0x102732a08 static WeSplitApp.$main() + 72 (WeSplitApp.swift:10)
56  WeSplit                                0x102732ab3 main + 67
57  dyld_sim                               0x102969ee9 start_sim + 10
58  dyld                                   0x108ced4fe start + 462

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7fff6da2dfec start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.utility-qos
0   dyld_sim                               0x102973a78 bool SwiftHashTable::equal<SwiftTypeProtocolConformanceLocationKey, SwiftTypeProtocolConformanceLocationKey>(SwiftTypeProtocolConformanceLocationKey const&, SwiftTypeProtocolConformanceLocationKey const&, unsigned char const*) const + 4
1   dyld_sim                               0x102985e3a unsigned int SwiftHashTable::getIndex<SwiftTypeProtocolConformanceLocationKey, SwiftTypeProtocolConformanceLocationKey>(SwiftTypeProtocolConformanceLocationKey const&, unsigned char const*) const + 126
2   dyld_sim                               0x102985d86 unsigned int SwiftHashTable::getPotentialTarget<SwiftTypeProtocolConformanceLocationKey, SwiftTypeProtocolConformanceLocationKey>(SwiftTypeProtocolConformanceLocationKey const&, unsigned char const*) const + 14
3   dyld_sim                               0x102984ebe dyld4::APIs::_dyld_find_protocol_conformance(void const*, void const*, void const*) const + 168
4   libswiftCore.dylib                  0x7fff30a40b9f swift_conformsToProtocolMaybeInstantiateSuperclasses(swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::TargetProtocolDescriptor<swift::InProcess> const*, bool) + 191
5   libswiftCore.dylib                  0x7fff30a408ce swift_conformsToProtocol + 78
6   libswiftCore.dylib                  0x7fff30a00cea swift::_conformsToProtocol(swift::OpaqueValue const*, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::TargetProtocolDescriptorRef<swift::InProcess>, swift::TargetWitnessTable<swift::InProcess> const**) + 42
7   libswiftCore.dylib                  0x7fff30a3ff3f swift::_checkGenericRequirements(__swift::__runtime::llvm::ArrayRef<swift::TargetGenericRequirementDescriptor<swift::InProcess> >, __swift::__runtime::llvm::SmallVectorImpl<void const*>&, std::__1::function<swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const* (unsigned int, unsigned int)>, std::__1::function<swift::TargetWitnessTable<swift::InProcess> const* (swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, unsigned int)>) + 1839
8   libswiftCore.dylib                  0x7fff30a3f742 swift::TargetProtocolConformanceDescriptor<swift::InProcess>::getWitnessTable(swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*) const + 290
9   libswiftCore.dylib                  0x7fff30a41391 swift_conformsToProtocolMaybeInstantiateSuperclasses(swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::TargetProtocolDescriptor<swift::InProcess> const*, bool) + 2225
10  libswiftCore.dylib                  0x7fff30a408ce swift_conformsToProtocol + 78
11  AttributeGraph                      0x7fff4ffaa1e8 AG::LayoutDescriptor::Builder::visit_element(AG::swift::metadata const*, AG::swift::metadata::ref_kind, unsigned long) + 102
12  AttributeGraph                      0x7fff4ff98ea7 AG::swift::metadata_visitor::visit_field(AG::swift::metadata const*, AG::swift::field_record const&, unsigned long) + 79
13  AttributeGraph                      0x7fff4ff986b8 AG::swift::metadata::visit(AG::swift::metadata_visitor&) const + 648
14  AttributeGraph                      0x7fff4ffaa2a4 AG::LayoutDescriptor::Builder::visit_element(AG::swift::metadata const*, AG::swift::metadata::ref_kind, unsigned long) + 290
15  AttributeGraph                      0x7fff4ff98ea7 AG::swift::metadata_visitor::visit_field(AG::swift::metadata const*, AG::swift::field_record const&, unsigned long) + 79
16  AttributeGraph                      0x7fff4ff986b8 AG::swift::metadata::visit(AG::swift::metadata_visitor&) const + 648
17  AttributeGraph                      0x7fff4ffab04b AG::LayoutDescriptor::make_layout(AG::swift::metadata const*, AGComparisonMode, AG::LayoutDescriptor::HeapMode) + 474
18  AttributeGraph                      0x7fff4ffac36c AG::(anonymous namespace)::LayoutCache::drain_queue(void*) + 142
19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7fff2011383a _dispatch_client_callout + 8
20  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7fff20124077 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 788
21  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7fff20124867 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 155
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7fff6da2f02e _pthread_wqthread + 256
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7fff6da2dffb start_wqthread + 15

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7fff6da2dfec start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7fff6da2dfec start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7fff6da2dfec start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6:: com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7fff6d9d4aba mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7fff6d9d4e2b mach_msg + 59
2   CoreFoundation                      0x7fff2036c440 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 319
3   CoreFoundation                      0x7fff20366ae3 __CFRunLoopRun + 1293
4   CoreFoundation                      0x7fff203660f3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 567
5   Foundation                          0x7fff2081c754 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 213
6   Foundation                          0x7fff2081c9cb -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 72
7   UIKitCore                           0x7fff2511a2d1 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 491
8   Foundation                          0x7fff20845550 __NSThread__start__ + 1025
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7fff6da324f4 _pthread_start + 125
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7fff6da2e00f thread_start + 15


Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000002  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x00007fff4ffc4b50  rdx: 0x0001000000000028
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x00007fff8b43c050  rbp: 0x00007ff7bd7d2fb0  rsp: 0x00007ff7bd7d2f70
   r8: 0x00007fff5d231685   r9: 0x00007fff86bdd330  r10: 0x0000000000000004  r11: 0x0000000000000072
  r12: 0x0000000000000002  r13: 0x00007ff7bd7d30a0  r14: 0x0000000000000040  r15: 0x00007fff8a918d88
  rip: 0x00007fff5c970f89  rfl: 0x0000000000010246  cr2: 0x00007fff5d2316b7
  
Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00000000 
Trap Number:     6


Binary Images:
    0x7fff5c697000 -     0x7fff5d4f2fff com.apple.SwiftUI (3.2.5.0.100) <c680d16f-a317-3c6e-87fa-141c22a715da> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/SwiftUI.framework/SwiftUI
    0x7fff30710000 -     0x7fff30acffff libswiftCore.dylib (*) <6013ecdd-c54d-3948-8b7c-e9f5613107f6> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib
       0x102728000 -        0x102733fff me.choo.minsoo.WeSplit (1.0) <d0012a27-d11a-39a0-b4eb-f874af3b5857> /Users/USER/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/Previews/Simulator Devices/B14B5709-F815-4854-ADB6-E7102668056B/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BA738B59-7D89-47AA-8012-6234AA6E65B0/WeSplit.app/WeSplit
    0x7fff4ff96000 -     0x7fff4ffcafff com.apple.AttributeGraph (3.2.1) <20c3feeb-4d9b-3501-be47-de9ae60ae297> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AttributeGraph.framework/AttributeGraph
       0x102ac4000 -        0x102af5fff com.apple.dt.PreviewsInjection (13.0) <385f7334-89cd-3998-bc1b-54dd898b38ad> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PreviewsInjection.framework/PreviewsInjection
    0x7fff2619e000 -     0x7fff261edfff com.apple.BoardServices (1.0) <d4742ff1-1051-348e-afb4-dcb3bc434c50> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BoardServices.framework/BoardServices
    0x7fff20110000 -     0x7fff20157fff libdispatch.dylib (*) <20999e62-bcc2-377e-8ce7-afda271eb914> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
    0x7fff202ec000 -     0x7fff2068bfff com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9) <c6308add-135b-3a70-9b81-1ce4d994c215> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
    0x7fff2c992000 -     0x7fff2c99afff com.apple.GraphicsServices (1.0) <adea8ae1-c723-351b-ac2e-22fd2c861c30> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
    0x7fff2438c000 -     0x7fff25934fff com.apple.UIKitCore (1.0) <3ef2c381-8193-3e3c-801f-925bd1050bd7> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
       0x102968000 -        0x1029b5fff dyld_sim (*) <3f15c197-2d43-3490-98ff-de85f18dadf2> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/dyld_sim
       0x108ce8000 -        0x108d53fff dyld (*) <7de33963-bbc5-3996-ba6e-f1d562c17c95> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff6da2c000 -     0x7fff6da37fff libsystem_pthread.dylib (*) <ee564342-d8f2-396d-b642-40092cf34d82> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
    0x7fff6d9d4000 -     0x7fff6da0afff libsystem_kernel.dylib (*) <c1d58a50-5a4d-3bcb-a1fc-ec0902ce34d3> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x7fff206fa000 -     0x7fff209b0fff com.apple.Foundation (6.9) <61dcc68e-1236-3624-bb6d-a3a850adf63a> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation

EOF
```

And the diagnostics:

```
MessageSendFailure: Message send failure for update

==================================

|  MessageError: Connection interrupted
```

Code:

ContentView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var checkAmount = 0.0
    @State private var numberOfPeople = 2
    @State private var tipPercentage = 20
    let tipPercentages = 0..<101
    
    var totalPerPerson: Double {
        let peopleCount = Double(numberOfPeople + 2)
        let tipSelection = Double(tipPercentage)

        let tipValue = checkAmount / 100 * tipSelection
        let grandTotal = checkAmount + tipValue
        let amountPerPerson = grandTotal / peopleCount

        return amountPerPerson
    }
    
    var total: Double {
        checkAmount + checkAmount / 100 * Double(tipPercentage)
    }
    
    @FocusState private var amountIsFocused: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    TextField("Amount", value: $checkAmount, format: .currency(code: Locale.current.currencyCode ?? "USD"))
                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                        .focused($amountIsFocused)
                
                    Picker("Number of People", selection: $numberOfPeople) {
                        ForEach(2..<100) {
                            Text("\($0) people")
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                Section {
                    Picker("Tip Percentage", selection: $tipPercentage) {
                        ForEach(tipPercentages, id: \.self) {
                            Text($0, format: .percent)
                        }
                    }
                } header: {
                    Text("How much tip do you want to leave?")
                }
            
                Section {
                    Text(totalPerPerson, format: .currency(code: Locale.current.currencyCode ?? "USD"))
                } header: {
                    Text("Amount per person")
                }
                
                Section {
                    Text(total, format: .currency(code: Locale.current.currencyCode ?? "USD"))
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("WeSplit")
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
                Spacer()
                
                Button("Done") {
                    amountIsFocused = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

WeSplitApp.swift

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct WeSplitApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I had to guess I would say it has something to do with `FocusState` because it is in the first line but Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. Comment out the `FocusState` related code and see if you can find the issue

Comment: If you have any bug in your code, the previews will not open. if you don't pass environment objects in your preview, you'll also have an issue. You need to be more specific, show an example of your code, show what you have tried so far. Follow these [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @HunterLion uploaded my codes

Comment: I believe @loremipsum has a point: start by providing a default value to `amountIsFocused`. This variable needs to be initialised.

Comment: @loremipsum That was the problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: @loremipsum Can you tell me what was wrong with my code?

Comment: @fel1x.mintchoco I’m away from my Mac right now but I’ll look at it this evening, what line did you comment out to get it working?

Comment: @fel1x.mintchoco try putting the focus state variable all the way on the top of the struct sometimes the SwiftUI wrappers act better when they are at the top.

Comment: @loremipsum It's in line 24. I put focus variable at the top of ContentView struct but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved by adding ZStack in Preview struct solved it.. This is maybe a bug.
[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70430440/why-focusstate-crashing-swiftui-preview)

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
       ZStack {
           ContentView()
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like it. Definitely submit it to Apple